# Noise texture not working on two planes at same time

Tags: uv, texture-painting

i have two separate planes, i have applied same noise texture in both the planes.
The problem is that it's only working on one of the plane.
Herein the image, you can see the upper ,although having same texture, is not showing the texture in lower plane.
What should i do now? Please help.[image]

Comment: .blend could help.
But... have you tried applying the scale: Ctrl+A in object mode with the planes selected

Answer (score 1):

You have two objects selected in **Object Mode**. The actual selected object is the one highlighted in a lighter orange. That is a) the last object selected and b) the **Active** object. You are seeing the Material attached to the active object.

As you can see in this screenshot, I have both objects selected as you do, and it appears that both have the same Material, but they do not.

[image]

If I invert the order in which I select the two objects, making the top plane the active object, you can see that the material is, in fact, different.

[image]

Select just the topmost plane and see what changes in the **Material Editor**.